# What next after coin creation?

Tags: litecoin, mining-theory

I am working on the new litecoin source 0.15.0.1. Change the required things in the source and compiled.

I am able to generate the blocks. Now How I can add a miner to this coin/network to mine this coin.

Any Help or resource links will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

- Download [CpuMiner](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cpuminer/files/) for your platform
- Unzip/Untar the file & Then Try:
  `./minerd -a scrypt -o http://127.0.0.1:19333 -u rpcuser -p rpcpass -t 1 -D --coinbase-addr=LTCorRespectiveAltCoinAddress -P`
- better to play,  `./mined --help` for params.